# ltsp-server-standalone uninstallable on 12,04

Tags: 12.04, dependencies, ltsp

I did a normal install of Ubuntu 12.04 using the Alt ISO. When I try to install ltsp-server-standalone I get:

```
ltsp@ubuntu32:~$ sudo apt-get install ltsp-server-standalone
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ltsp-server-standalone : 
     Depends: ldm-server but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: ltsp-server but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: ltspfs but it is not installable
     Depends: nbd-server (>= 1:2.9.25-2) but it is not installable
     Recommends: isc-dhcp-server but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: pulseaudio-esound-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I would like to use 12.04 because alot of the ltsp guides are based on it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS since it provides the same stability as 12.04 LTS, newer packages, and will last you past the upcoming EOL of Ubuntu 12.04. Additionally, more people will be able to provide support to Ubuntu 14.04, and most guides written for 12.04 should be compatible with 14.04, give or take a few things.

However, if you insist on using 12.04, using:

```
apt-get clean
```

as root (e.g. sudo) and:

```
apt-get -f install
```

(again as root) should fix this issue.

Then attempt to install ltsp-server-standalone. If those two commands did not resolve the issue for you, check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) for additional troubleshooting.